# Emit a value after onNext is called after a particular time

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to emit a random value 10 secs after onNext is called. So onNext will be called for 12345 and 10 secs later onNext should be called for a random number. What is the best way to achieve this using RxJava? Thanks in advance.

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    subscriber.onNext(12345);
}).subscribeOn(...)
.observeOn(...)
.subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>(){
    @Override
    public void onNext(Long aLong) {
        //Do Something
    }
})
```

Comment: You can put this logic in the subscriber -> {} method. A timer or something can do the job. It's jus tmy option, but I don't think RxJava is meant to deal with complex cases out-of-box. It's a good idea to write your logic of how to emit your data in pure Java, when it is a complex case.

Comment: Isn't there an operator or something for the same?

Comment: This case seams to be a very particular one, but maybe someone has a good idea in SO

Comment: That is a particularly bad advice. One of the main reasons to use RxJava is to leverage its ability to convert complex use-cases into simple stream composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you emit your '12345' value right away, then solution is trivial. Just merge this observable with `timer` and you will get this kind of behavior. However, I am going to assume that your logic in OnSubscribe method you pass to `create` is doing some work and will emit the value once it is ready ( i.e. network request ). In that case, you need leverage both `flatMap` and `merge` operators. Something like this should suffice.

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    subscriber.onNext(12345);
})
  .flatMap(value -> Observable.just(value)
        .mergeWith(Observable.timer(10, TimeUnits.SECONDS).map(/* define your "random" value here */))
  )
  .subscribeOn(...)
  .observeOn(...)
  .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>(){
      @Override
      public void onNext(Long aLong) {
        //Do Something
      }
  })
```

It will take your value and convert it into and observable, which emits this value right away and starts a timer for 10 seconds to emit something else.

***Note:*** Beware that this will take every item your observable emits and create this delayed second response for each of them. So if you plan on emitting multiple values from your source observable, you need to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks. This is the perfect solution.